# How to deal with interdependent JUnit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I have a question about JUnit testing.

Our JUnit suite is testing various functions that we wrote that interact with our memory system.

The way our system was designed, requires it to be static, and therefore initialized prior to the running of the tests.

The problem we are having is that when subsequent tests are run, they are affected by tests prior to it, so it is possible (and likely) that we are getting false positive, or innaccurate failures.

Is there a way to maintain the testing order of our JUnit tests, but have it re-initialize the entire system, as if testing on the system from scratch.

The only option we can think of is to write a method that does this, and call it at the end of each test, but as there are lots and lots of things that need to be reset this way, I am hoping there is a simpler way to do this.

Comment: Also, writing a new method to reinitialize would be incredibly costly.

Comment: I think I misread this comment.  You mean costly to __develop__, not lengthy to run - correct?  It sounds like your system isn't designed well from a testability standpoint - but I'm sure that's old news.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I meant costly from an efficiency standpoint, like, longer run-time, and inefficient implementation.  Not from a development standpoint.

Comment: Furthermore, it's not that consequent tests are dependent on previous tests, they are just being effected by it. When I say maintain testing ordering, I mean, continuing to run the tests despite any interruption due to "resetting."  This may still have issues in testability design, but I really see no way around my current hurdle due to the memory system being static.  (The @Before @After tags seem like something along the lines of what I want, but still this seems more efficient from only a code-volume standpoint.  I guess what I was hoping for was some generic @Reset or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen problems with tests many times where they depend on each other (sometimes deliberately!).

Firstly you need to setup a setUp method:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    super.setUp();
    // Now clear, reset, etc all your static data.
}
```

This is automatically run by JUnit before each test and will reset the environment. You can add one after as well, but before is better for ensuring a clean starting point.

The order of your tests is usually the order they are in the test class. But this should never be assumed and it's a really bad idea to base code on that.

Go back to the [documentation](http://www.junit.org/). If you need more information.

Comment: If you mention strategies to help test performance, particularly with large setup's and teardowns used by only a few tests, I'd upvote you twice if I could.

Comment: The first trick to improving test performance is to ensure that the tests that are slow, actually need the long setup. I've often seen what are really unit tests being coded as integration tests. Secondly, my experience is that annotation driven junit 4.5 doesn't fully support setups around test runs, just classes and tests. So you have to go back to 3.8 TestSuites if you have real issues. A lot of it comes down to what you are actually trying to do. In memory databases and web servers for example can speed up integration testing.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I took to this kind of problem was to do partial reinitialization before each test.  Each test knows the preconditions that it requires, and the setup ensures that they are true.  Not sure if this will be relevant for you.  Relying on order often ends up being a continuing PITA - being able to run tests by themselves is better.

Oh yeah - there's one "test" that's run as the beginning of a suite that's responsible for static initialization.

Comment: Any reason why you don't use a setup method or equivalent?

Comment: @Arafangion - Yes - same as Anuj - it's very expensive to do for every test.  Also, in my case, it's doing some relatively lengthy DB initialization that I don't need to redo if I'm just, say, debugging a single test.  Also, I like to use some test-style validations to ensure correct execution.  In my case, and I suspect in Anuj's case also, I'm doing integration testing - not really unit testing per se - but with JUnit.

Comment: Then you have a (potential) setup that contains logic that shouldn't be used by all the tests. Logic that isn't relevant to the test is confusing, and suggests that you need to set up another testsuite. Nothing is more confusing, however, than tests that apparently depend on other tests.

Comment: @Arafangion - this gets a bit religious.  The DB setup is required by all the tests - just not very often, and certainly not when running each test.  It's run as part of a CI suite several times a day under Hudson because time isn't an issue there.  Otherwise, I only run it when it's clear that it needs running.

Comment: I do agree that these topics get religious! :) I am only arguing that the DB setup should only be used for those tests that need it - you say that it's 'required by all the tests', but then you contradict yourself and say that it's just not very often, and certainly not when running each test'.

Comment: @Arafangion - all tests require that the DB be set up with this first test.  No tests modify anything in the DB that is set up by this test, so it doesn't have to be rerun very often.  Changes in other areas may require it to be rerun.  The areas set up by the test often are new, and the setup must be tested in some way, so it is a test in order to use normal test validation methods since there's a risk of failure.  It could be split into a non-test of some kind, and a validation that runs at setup, but this would make for more harder-to-maintain code, and the validation would take time.

Comment: Yeah, my testing is very similar to yours Ed.  It's not that consequent tests are **dependent** on previous tests, they are just being effected by it.  When I say maintain testing ordering, I meant more like, continuing to run the tests despite any interruption in reinitialization.

Comment: @AnujSuer9 - "interruption in reinitialization" - sorry, don't understand, can you rephrase?

Comment: I'm sorry, that should have read "interruption _due to_ reinitialization.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [TestNG](http://testng.org), which supports test dependencies for this kind of functional testing (JUnit is a unit testing framework):

```
@Test
public void f1() {}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "f1")
public void f2() {}
```